# DAG bipartite matchings vs. minimal path cover

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Whenever $G=(V,E)$ is a DAG, we can look at the induced bipartite graph and find a maximum matching. Then the number of unmatched vertices in each part of the bipartition is supposedly exactly the same as the number of paths in a minimal path cover for $G$. We proved this for the special case when $G$ is a tree, or exactly 1 edge more than a tree. However, we can't seem to find a proof for the general case.

Comment: Can you give some insight of what do you call the induced bipartite graph?

Comment: Both parts have the same nodes as the original graph, and there is an edge from v in the left part to w in the right part if (v,w) is an edge in the original graph.

Comment: You assume your DAG to be connected?

Comment: And are the path in the minimal path cover vertex disjoint?

Comment: G is connected. I'm looking for a path cover which covers each vertex at least once, and where all paths originate at the source.